# What software do I need to use a Playstation DualShock 2 pad on OS X?

Tags: controllers

So I've got a DualShock 2 pad and a USB adapter, and I want to use it with a Mac. What software do I need to install for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Whether the DualShock 2 will work with your mac will be dependent on the USB adapter that you have I would think. I believe that there are several different types of adapters and some advertise as being mac compatible, but most don't.

As far as I know, the DualShock 3 works natively with Macs over bluetooth though, so that could perhaps be a better option.